# How do I filter part of a string using regex?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

Using PowerShell I am able to get the lines from a file which contain the needed text:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Attributes !Directory+!System | Get-Content | Select-String "tshtml"
```

This gives the result below:

```
 templateUrl: '/tshtml/generic/gkeyvalue/gkeyvalue.html'
 templateUrl: '/tshtml/generic/permission/permission.html'
 templateUrl: '/tshtml/generic/permission2/permission2.html'
```

But now I want part of this as output:

```
 /generic/gkeyvalue/gkeyvalue.html
 /generic/permission/permission.html
 /generic/permission2/permission2.html
```

How do I do that?  I am reading about regex, but I am not getting much about it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... | Select-String "tshtml" | ForEach { $_.Line -replace "^.*(?=/generic)|'$" }
```

To replace the start of a line leading up to `/generic`, and the `'` from the end of the line, with nothing.

or

```
Select-String "tshtml" | ForEach { if ($_.Line -match "'/tshtml(.*)'") { $Matches[1] } }
```

To capture the text between the `''` and output it.

Comment: Even simpler for the section option: `...|Get-Content|?{$_ -match "'/tshtml(.*)'"}|%{ $Matches[1]}` There's no need for the `Select-String` and then matching, just do it all at once.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yeah. Or use select-string to do it all at once  `... | Select-String "'/tshtml(.*)'" | ForEach {$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value}`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
... | Select-String "tshtml"|awk '{print $2}'| tr -d "'"
```

Comment: Assuming you have a Windows build of `awk` and `tr` to use, the output of `Select-String` converted to plain string includes the filename as well, so this would need to be `{print $3}` to get the right output.

Comment: I know i could do it easily using sed/awk but not aware about how to do it on windows :( and I dont have windows build of sed/awk/tr